# Javascript: Export array with objects that refer to functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I'm using an array to populate a settings page and some of the buttons have functions attached.

Here's what I want to do. 
In one file export an array with objects that refer to functions within the same file
OR
export a class, then access the array from within that class, referring to functions inside the class.

// import file

```js
import Settings from './Settings';
console.log(Settings.settingsArray);
```

// export file

```
export const settingsArray = [
  {
    title: " ",
    data: [
      {
        title: "Export data",
        func: this.exportData
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: " ",
    data: [
      { 
        title: "Set custom code",
        func: this.showDialog
      },
    ]
  }
]

exportData = () => {
    // some code
};

showDialog = () => {
    // some code
};
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What problem are you running into?

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to anything useful in this scope. `exportData` should already exist in order to be referred in an array. It should be referred without `this`.

Comment: Well, I used to have the entire settings tree with every function in a context which is provided to the entire app. It worked fine, except for the bad practice, until I tried saving to react native AsyncStorage using JSON.stringify, because it doesn't like functions. So I'm trying to put it in a separate file, now I just have to figure out how to connect to the context from that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `this` keyword and create the functions before using them:

```
const exportData = () => {
    // some code
};

const showDialog = () => {
    // some code
};

export const settingsArray = [
  {
    title: " ",
    data: [
      {
        title: "Export data",
        func: exportData
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: " ",
    data: [
      { 
        title: "Set custom code",
        func: showDialog
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Alternatively declare them as `function`s and take advantage of hoisting.